# Modified FileInputStream (certain part of the file)

Tags: java, file, inputstream

How can I get a `FileInputStream` of an existing file which doesn't go through the whole file but rather goes through a specified part of the file (from byte `m` till byte `n`)?

Edit: I need the `FileInputStream` to submit it to [org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = ...
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
long m = .... 
fis.getChannel().position(m);
int n = ... 
byte[] buffer = new byte[n];
fis.read(buffer);
```

Comment: The `read()` method isn't guaranteed to fill the buffer, and you haven't answered the part of the question about 'till byte `n`'.